# Why Managed module Is faster than Unmanaged module in C#

Tags: c#, performance, compiler-construction, il

I reading a book( CLR via c#)in the book writer speak about IL and managed module that managed module compiling in  native cpu code and then execute in the book writer said that Managed module Is faster than Unmanaged module.my question is why Managed module Is faster than Unmanaged module but for in Managed module first compile to IL and then compile in native cpu.

Comment: i have read that book, can u point me where it says so ?

Comment: there are always certain condition where this can be applicable, but in reality a well written Unmanaged code will always beat the managed code execution speed!

Comment: @AppDeveloper meh; it depends on the context - it a lot of cases they'll be pretty similar - it really depends on where the delays are.

Comment: The point is that managed code uses more memory and CPU but you can implement algorithmic optimizations with much less code. For a given time to implement something you can usually outperform C/C++ because you can concentrate more on data structures and algorithmic stuff.

Comment: The author also goes on and gives examples of where this may be the case. Read a little further and you'll get the answer to your question. He's not saying that managed code is generally faster than native code.

Comment: @MarcGravell - i agree, but with all due respect, is there any possible situation where well written, well unmanaged code execute slower then managed one?

Comment: Agree with @AppDeveloper. I've yet to see a realistic example that is faster in managed than native code.

Comment: When writing managed vs native code, you usually end up solving the same problem in different ways because of the differences in language features, frameworks, etc. So you might end up comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez - still, Apple & Orange are good for health! Which is better one is the real question!

Comment: oranges -- if you're catching a cold, and apples -- if you have diarrhea ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(What I wrote below is not mine, it is copy-pasted from a book: [`CLR via C#, Page No 14`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045))

---

#### There are many reasons why a managed code can outperform unmanaged code

> When the JIT compiler compiles the IL code into native machine code at
>   run time, the compiler knows more about the execution environment than
>   an unmanaged compiler would know.

Some ways in which managed code can outperform unmanaged code

- A JIT compiler can determine if the application is running on an
  Intel Pentium 4 CPU and produce native code that takes the advantage
  of any special instruction offered by the CPU. Usually, unmanaged
  application are compiled for the lowest-common denominator of the CPU
  and avoid using special instruction that would give application
  performance boost.
- A JIT compiler can determine when a certain test always fail on the machine that it is running on. Consider the example

  ```
  if (num_of_cpu > 1)
  {        
  }
  ```

This code causes the JIT to not generate any CPU instruction if the machine has only One CPU.

- The CLR could profile the code's execution and recompile the IL into a native code while the application runs. The recompiled code will be reorganized to reduce incorrect branch prediction depending on the observed execution patterns. Current version of C# do not do this, but future version might.

Comment: i can read this book u just copy and past

Comment: yup ofcs, that is the point!

Comment: if the book has better point then i can think of, why write different?

Comment: I've seen a lot of hypothetical reasons about why managed code "could" beat unmanaged code, but I have yet to see a real example.

Comment: @AppDeveloper - I'm assuming from context that the whole post was intended on being a quote, and made an edit to that effect.  If some of it is your own text, please edit that back out of the block quotes.

Comment: @mehrdad I am using a C++/CLR project which has two identical methods one managed and one unmanaged. They both contain a simple for loop that iterates to 99999. The managed code seems to always outperform the unmanaged code.    EDIT!!!: Oops I had the managed and unmanaged flag around the wrong way!!! :D